# How to send status to other class in JAVA

Tags: java

I have three classes serviceManager,serviceMasterHandler and WokerThread.serviceManager instantiate ServiceMasterHandler,ServiceMasterHandler instantiate and start workerThread.
I want to implements that each class started successfully it's send status to calling upper classes.
All ideas on how to implement is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you starting classes in separate threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already heard about [`PropertyChangeEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html) and associated classes (like [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) and [`PropertyChangeSupport`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html)) ? If not, go take a look at them .. And read the chapter in [Java tutorial about ProperttyChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html). Notice that, although it's defined in a Swing context, elements from `java.beans` can perfectly be used anywhere else, as they are not Swing-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to have a status flag at each upperclasses and update it to started in the child classess in child's constructor or any init method if you have.